# Using @wire and getFieldValue is returning undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, js, getfieldvalue

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getAcc from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.getAcc';

import F1 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.f1';
import F2 from '@salesforce/schema/Account.f2';

const fields = [F1, F2];

export default class LightningDatatableExample extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api searchKey = '';
    @api recordId;

    @track error;
    @track data;
    @track items;

    @api Field1;
    @api Field2;
    @api concatenatedFields;

   get Field1() {
        return getFieldValue(this.wiredAccounts.data, F1) ;
    }
   
    get Field2() {
        return getFieldValue(this.wiredAccounts.data, F2);
    }
    get concatenatedFields(){
        return `${this.Field1} ${this.Field2}`;
      }

      @wire(getAcc, { searchKey: '$searchKey', fields: fields }) wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {

        if (data) {

            this.items = data; 

       
            let sections = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-accordion-section')
            sections.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {
                currentValue.label = this.concatenatedFields;

            })

            this.error = undefined;


        } else if (error) {
            
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;

        }
    }
```

////HTML

```
           <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class={multiple}>
                <template if:true={data}>
                    <template for:each={data} for:item="acc">
                        <lightning-accordion-section key={acc.Id} name={acc.Name} label={concatenatedFields}>
                            <lightning-card  >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template if:true={data}>
  <template for:each={data} for:item="acc">
    <lightning-accordion-section key={acc.Id} name={acc.Name} label={concatenatedFields}>
```

Should be:

```
<template if:true={items} for:each={items} for:item="acc">
  <lightning-accordion-section key={acc.Id} name={acc.Name} label={acc.concatenatedFields}>
```

Notice how you're setting `this.items`, so your template should be using that as well.

The `getFieldValue` method should only be used with `getRecord`.

The wire method should update the incoming data to match:

```
@wire(getAcc, { searchKey: '$searchKey', fields }) wiredAccounts({data, error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.items = data.map(
      (acc)=>
      ({...acc, // Copy the original incoming attributes
        concatenatedFields: `${acc.Field1} ${acc.Field2}` // And create new attribute
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Improved it, but still displays 'undefined undefined' in label